# How to write a swiss pairing software

Tags: learning, software

I'm thinking about to develop an online service to provide free software for helping chess tournaments organizers with pairing systems like swiss, round robin, team-swiss, team-round robin.

Could you, please, send me some learning materials how those pairing systems work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start with the section of the FIDE web site which describes the [Swiss Rules](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=18&view=category). This has sections giving detailed descriptions of the different systems for making the pairings along with much other useful information.

It is also worth looking at the [FIDE Tournament Rules](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=20&view=category) which includes tables for round robin tournaments and descriptions of tie break methods which it is good to also have in a pairing program.

Comment: @harcos You're welcome. If you found the answer useful you can click on the up arrow.

Comment: @harcos did you write some code ?

Comment: yes, hopefully it's goind to be online in the next month, are you interested, @mounaim ?

Comment: Sure @harcos ;) I do some Java programming and I would like to know how to implement the swiss pairing method :)

Comment: All my implementation is based on the rules given by Brian: http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=18&view=category

I can help when you have started and you are stuck